# will MSDTC services work for multiple login's under single transaction scope?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, transactions, msdtc

i am currently working on oracle database connection with c# . Does MSDTC is required while opening the same connection with different user login under single [transaction scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) .